# For the 2nd derivative of $f(x)$ to be continuous, does $f(x)$ need to be continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

For example:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}\arctan(x) & |x| < 1 \\ \frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{3x}{4} & |x|\ge1 \end{cases}$

where

$f''(x) = \begin{cases}-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2} & |x| < 1 \\ -\frac{x}{2} & |x|\ge1 \end{cases}$

$f''(1)=-\frac{1}{2}\\
f''(-1)=\frac{1}{2}$

The second derivative seems to be continuous, but because:

$\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}\ne\frac{1}{12}+\frac{3}{4}$

and

$\arctan(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}\ne-\frac{1}{12}-\frac{3}{4}$

my book says the second derivative is not continuous.  Is this really a requirement?  Why does continuity of the second derivative depend on the original function?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: Well the function you defined as the second derivative is continous,but by definition of the derivative you can't have $f'(\pm 1)$ hence second derivative also can't be defined at $\pm 1$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is not continuous at $1$: the limit from the right is $\pi/4$ and the limit from the left is $5/6$.

So already the *first* derivative at $1$ does not exist. A function that is not defined at a point cannot be differentiable there, can it?

The same considerations apply at $-1$.

Comment: So $f''(x)=g(x)$ as its own entity is continuous but it doesn't work as the second derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: @Thomas The function you are calling $g$ coincides with the second derivative of $f$ where $f''$ exists. That's all you can say. But $f'(1)$ and $f'(-1)$ don't exist, so neither $f''(1)$ nor $f''(-1$ exist.